# Protect single JSF action with Spring Security

Tags: jsf, spring-security

I am developing JSF + Spring Security web application.
I need to create form accessible for unauthenticated users.
When user submits form it is necessary to authenticate user (redirect user to CAS login page) and process submit only after user is successfully authenticated. User must stay on the same page after submit.

examplePageWithForm.xhtml:

```
<html xmlns:h=http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html>
    <h:form id=”myForm”>
        .... some other commponents, including actions which does not requires autentication ....
        <h:inputText value="#{myBackingBean.someTextValue}" />
        <h:commandButton value="loginAndSubmitForm" 
                         action="#{myBackingBean.actProcessSubmitedForm()}">
    </h:form>
</html>
```

Is it possible “protect” single JSF action with spring security? Or maybe some alternative solution is available?

Currently using Spring security I found only possibility to protect some URLs, but commandButton fires “HTTP POST” to page which does not requires authentication (\examplePageWithForm.jsf), so login step never occurs.

Comment: How about ajax POST ?

Comment: `I found only possibility to protect some URLs`. So, I guess you need to make some research to discover if it's possible to secure POST requests with Spring Security. If you find it possible, try to apply to JSF (you need to remember the previous request after the authentication).